# Disagreement between "About this computer" and /etc/lsb-release

Tags: upgrade, versions

I have a Dell XPS that had Ubuntu 12.4 factory installed, which I upgraded 12.4->12.10->13.4->13.10 using the Software Updater.  When I look at `/etc/lsb-release`, I see what I expect:

```
% cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=13.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=saucy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 13.10"
```

However, when I go to the little gear icon in the upper-right corner of my screen and choose "About this computer", it says in large letters that I am running `ubuntu 12.04 LTS`.

What is behind these two sources?  Is something likely out of sync?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see, `/etc/lsb-release` shows the true current version.

The gear icon >> *About this computer*, opens *System Settings >> Details*.

The *Details* dialog box, however, is not fetching the system settings from `/etc/lsb-release`. Instead, it displays a graphic file that has the version number as part of the image: `/usr/share/gnome-control-center/ui/UbuntoLogo.png`.

Apparently, on your factory installed system, when an upgrade is performed, this graphic file is not replaced; so *Details* continues to show the version that was originally installed.

Comment: Interestingly, in the `dpkg -L gnome-control-center-data` output, I see this:  `/usr/share/gnome-control-center/ui/UbuntuLogo.png
diverted by dell-e-star to: /usr/share/gnome-control-center/ui/UbuntuLogo.png.diverted`.

Comment: Interesting. I had figured Dell made some changes to the install image, since since `gnome-control-center-data` is auto updated when `gnome-control-center` is updated. They ought to update the diverted image, but they're not. It's probably not recommended to mess with their install. I would say either just ignore the difference, edit the diverted image, or replace the .diverted image with a renamed copy of the newer one (download the .deb and extract the .png and rename .diverted). I edited the wording of the answer a little.

Comment: I guess I'll just ignore it.  The only harm I can see it causing is if someone (an administrator from work, who issued me this machine) opens up the Control Center and sees the 12.4 version and proceeds to do something that wouldn't make sense on a 13.10 machine.  But that's a pretty unlikely scenario.

Answer (score 0):

To extend chaskes's answer, I looked up the package containing the offending file, which turned out to be `gnome-control-center-data`.  You could likely fix the problem by reinstalling that package using your favourite package manager.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a later version of this package according to `apt-get` - I have `1:3.6.3-0ubuntu45.1`.

Comment: I gather from your remarks above (sorry, haven't got enough rep to comment on others' posts) that Dell set up a rule with `dpkg-divert` to stop the file from being overwritten.  If you'd like the file to be updated, you can use the same utility with the `--remove` command to allow dpkg to put the file where the System Settings expects it.

Comment: Thanks @Aoeuid.  If this isn't causing any harm then I think I'll just ignore it.  Understanding it has been very helpful.